# Problema al intentar volver a renderizar luego de setear un estado de React

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, usestate, useeffect

Sé que de alguna forma debiera escuchar los cambios que realiza el estado para que se vuelva renderizar o algo así pero no logro setear el estado.

```
const ChoosePokemon = (pokemon) => {

let [choosePokemon, setChoosePokemon] = useState([]); let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); let [pokemonToBatle, setPokemonToBatle] = useState([]); let [cpu, setCpu]= useState({});

const handleChosePokemon = (pokemon)=> { console.log(pokemon); setPokemonToBatle(pokemon); console.log(pokemonToBatle); } useEffect(async () => { if (ids) { let pokemon = new PokemonServices(); let model = new PokemonModel(); let all = []; await Promise.all(ids.map(async (id) => { let eachPokemon = await pokemon.find(https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}); let eachPokemonFull = model.getFromObject(eachPokemon); let final = eachPokemonFull.getStats(eachPokemonFull); all.push(final); })) setChoosePokemon(all); setLoading(false); }

}, []) const Chose = ({ pokemon }) => { return ( <> <button onClick={(e)=> handleChosePokemon(pokemon)}>

      <img src={pokemon.imageDetails} alt={pokemon.name} />
      </button>
    </div>
  </>
)

} return ( <> {!loading && !pokemonToBatle && Hi!! Chose a Pokemon to batle!} {loading ? pokemonToBatle.length == 0 &&
estoy cargando
: choosePokemon.map((pokemon) =>)} {pokemonToBatle.length < 0 ?
tengo pokemon ya
: null} </> );

}

export default ChoosePokemon;
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: tu post es puro código puedes dar una mejor descripción del error o problema que presentas?